# Rename files failed using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, rename

I'm trying to rename all files in a directory using this code:

```
import os
count = 0
path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\imageye\\data"
for i in os.listdir(path):
    print i
    os.rename(i,str(count)+ '.'+ i.split('.')[-1])
    count+=1
```

But I got this error:

```
00ROOSE-MUSK-top-videoSixteenByNine3000.jpg
WindowsErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ab7dde0493e3> in <module>()
      3 for i in os.listdir(path):
      4     print i
----> 5     os.rename(i,str(count)+ '.'+ i.split('.')[-1])
      6     count+=1
WindowsError: [Error 2] The specified file can not be found
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: Try to use forward slash `/` for directories so instead of `C:\\Folder 1\\Folder 2\\` user `C:/Folder 1/Folder 2`

Use this For Loop:

```
for i in os.listdir(path):
    print(i)
    newfilename="New_"+str(count)+ '.'+ i.split('.')[-1]
    os.rename(path+"/"+i , path+"/"+newfilename)
    count+=1
```

explanation:
Error which you received was because it was not able to find the path of the file. So I have added the full path of the file. Hope this will resolve your issue.

Thanks.